# IOS-XR - How to get bandwidth policed on an interface

Tags: qos, policing, cisco-ios-xr

How can I get in a straight-forward way the bandwidth policed on a certain interface on IOS-XR.

In IOS, I execute

```
show policy-map interface Gi1/1.1000
```

And I get clearly the BW policed on interface

```
 GigabitEthernet1/1.1000

  Service-policy output: cos-REF0186382

    class-map: class-default (match-any)
      Match: any 
      police :
        10600000 bps 1250000 limit 1250000 extended limit
      Earl in slot 1 :
        0 bytes
        30 second offered rate 0 bps
        aggregate-forwarded 0 bytes action: transmit
        exceeded 0 bytes action: drop
        aggregate-forward 0 bps exceed 0 bps 
      Earl in slot 5 :
        1111006353149 bytes
        30 second offered rate 204584 bps
        aggregate-forwarded 1082398797572 bytes action: transmit
        exceeded 28607555577 bytes action: drop
        aggregate-forward 210768 bps exceed 0 bps
```

How can I get similar information on IOS-XR. 
By similar command, I get counters but no info about configured policed BW.

```
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:PE2#show policy-map interface Te0/0/0/1.1000
TenGigE0/0/0/1.1000 direction input: Service Policy not installed

TenGigE0/0/0/1.1000 output: cos-REF123456789

Class class-default
  Classification statistics          (packets/bytes)     (rate - kbps)
    Matched             :                   0/0                    0
    Transmitted         :                   0/0                    0
    Total Dropped       :                   0/0                    0
    Policy cos-po2-REF123456789 Class cos-vo-1
      Classification statistics          (packets/bytes)     (rate - kbps)
        Matched             :                   0/0                    0
        Transmitted         :                   0/0                    0
        Total Dropped       :                   0/0                    0
      Policing statistics                (packets/bytes)     (rate - kbps) 
        Policed(conform)    :                   0/0                    0
        Policed(exceed)     :                   0/0                    0
        Policed(violate)    :                   0/0                    0
        Policed and dropped :                   0/0                  
        Policed and dropped(parent policer)  : N/A
      Queueing statistics
        Queue ID                             : 65744 
        High watermark                       : N/A 
        Inst-queue-len  (packets)            : 0
        Avg-queue-len                        : N/A 
        Taildropped(packets/bytes)           : 0/0
        Queue(conform)      :                   0/0                    0
        Queue(exceed)       :                   0/0                    0
        RED random drops(packets/bytes)      : 0/0

    Policy cos-po2-REF123456789 Class cos-nm-1
      Classification statistics          (packets/bytes)     (rate - kbps)
        Matched             :                   0/0                    0
        Transmitted         :                   0/0                    0
        Total Dropped       :                   0/0                    0
      Queueing statistics
        Queue ID                             : 65746 
        High watermark                       : N/A 
        Inst-queue-len  (packets)            : 0
        Avg-queue-len                        : N/A 
        Taildropped(packets/bytes)           : 0/0
        Queue(conform)      :                   0/0                    0
        Queue(exceed)       :                   0/0                    0
        RED random drops(packets/bytes)      : 0/0

        WRED profile for WRED Curve 1
        RED Transmitted (packets/bytes)            : N/A
        RED random drops(packets/bytes)            : 0/0
        RED maxthreshold drops(packets/bytes)      : N/A 
        RED ecn marked & transmitted(packets/bytes): N/A 
    Policy cos-po2-REF123456789 Class class-default
      Classification statistics          (packets/bytes)     (rate - kbps)
        Matched             :                   0/0                    0
        Transmitted         :                   0/0                    0
        Total Dropped       :                   0/0                    0
      Queueing statistics
        Queue ID                             : 65747 
        High watermark                       : N/A 
        Inst-queue-len  (packets)            : 0
        Avg-queue-len                        : N/A 
        Taildropped(packets/bytes)           : 0/0
        Queue(conform)      :                   0/0                    0
        Queue(exceed)       :                   0/0                    0
        RED random drops(packets/bytes)      : 0/0

        WRED profile for WRED Curve 1
        RED Transmitted (packets/bytes)            : N/A
        RED random drops(packets/bytes)            : 0/0
        RED maxthreshold drops(packets/bytes)      : N/A 
        RED ecn marked & transmitted(packets/bytes): N/A
```

Comment: We would need to see the config.

Comment: I would agree with Jordan.  I clearly see counters incrementing on one of my ASRs.

Comment: What I'm looking is not a command who show me the counter but the policed bandwidth per class. As we can on IOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I don't have a system actually in front of me to get you actual output, but look for "show qos interface ..." and that should have the configured hardware values for all the QoS parameters.

The CLI is going to be *something* like:

```
show qos interface gigE 0/0/0/0.101 ingress
```

(it might actually be "input" or "output" instead of "ingress" or "egress" but with a little question-mark magic you'll be able to find it.   You'll have a whole bunch of output that shows you all the policer rates, actions, and token bucket depths.  It's actually a very useful little command.   ;-)

Comment: Yes. This is what I was looking for.  It's effectively "input" / "output" . Thanks.